# Convert One Column in Python Dataframe to List

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of only one column of data.  I want to convert the column of data into a list.  The column has float datatype.

For example:

```
ColA
341321432
132184900
173840143
1432473928
```

Desired: 
341321432, 132184900, 173840143, 1432473928

Below is my Python code:

```
df_gearME = pd.read_excel('Gear M&Es.xlsx')
df_gearME['ColA'].to_list()
```

But the error I get is as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_list'
```

Comment: The method is `tolist()` - no `_`

Comment: ah, I see ... that gives me the values listed out vertically ... how do I get the output horizontally?

Comment: It's just a list - how the environment you're in chooses to display it is something different - ipython/jupyter will try to pretty print it for instance... if you want to display it in a certain way - you have to format it in a certain way...

Comment: @JonClements you're right that the method is `tolist()` but the pandas 0.24.0 documentation says it's `to_list()`. Do you know why the documentation lists it with an `_`?

Comment: @NicholasNelson nope... sorry... not a developer for either libraries.

Comment: @JonClements thank you so very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do:

```
>>> list(df_gearME.ColA)
[341321432, 132184900, 173840143, 1432473928]
```

Or print it for horizontal output:

```
>>> print(list(f_gearME.ColA))
[341321432, 132184900, 173840143, 1432473928]
```

Comment: when I use the above code, it provides the output vertically .... anyway I can get it horizontally?